# Comparing each rows in 2 dataframes using Spark and storing result in new column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Please I need help on comparing 2 data-frames with the desired output like shown in the last image below. I have 2 data-frames with column ID as the joining key. Now I want to compare columns N_1 with N_2, same as N_3 with N_4 and N_5 with N_6. Then the result of each comparison would be in a separate column indicating "Y" if the compared columns are matching and a "N" if they are not.
Ultimately, I want to create a last column where if any Compared columns in each row is "Y", the matching is "Y". Please see the last image for my desired output.
I cannot come upi with the scala code to do this. I'm using Spark. Please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `join` both dataframe, then use `withColumn` for new columns. You will find a lot sources in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat calling `withColumn` to generate columns `N_1=N_2`，`N_3=N_4`，`N_5=N_6`，`MATCHING`

```
df1.join(df2, df1.col("ID") === df2.col("ID"))
   .withColumn("N_1=N_2", when(df1.col("N_1") === df1.col("N_2"), lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N")))
   .withColumn("N_3=N_4", when(df1.col("N_3") === df2.col("N_4"), lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N")))
   .withColumn("N_5=N_6", when(df2.col("N_5") === df2.col("N_6"), lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N")))
   .withColumn("MATCHING", when(col("N_1=N_2") === "Y" || col("N_3=N_4") === "Y" || col("N_5=N_6") === "Y", lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N")))
```

Comment: For `Matching` column logic combined with `or` not `and`

Comment: thank you for this. I thought of this except for the last .withColumn for "MATCHING". I want to leave the MATCHING column open such that as long as any of the compared column is a "Y", then the MATCHING column should be "Y" not that all of them must be a "Y" for the MATCHING column to be "Y". I think what I need to change in the code you wrote is the "&&" to "or". Is that making any sense?

Comment: just replace && with ||